# How to post strings via ssl by using Synapse lib?

Tags: delphi, http, post, ssl, https

I'm using the [Synapse Library](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/) and today i want to know how i can send strings via post request to a webserver which uses ssl.

Here is my existing code:

```
procedure TForm1.syn;
var
  Position: Integer;
  URL, Params: string;
  Response: TMemoryStream;
  SynHttp: THTTPSend;
  Socket: TTCPBlockSocket;
begin
  Response := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Socket := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;
  SynHttp := THTTPSend.Create;
  URL := 'https://gitlab.com';

  try
       Position := Pos('https', URL);
       if Position <> 0 then begin //
         SynHttp.Sock.CreateWithSSL(TSSLOpenSSL);
         SynHttp.Sock.SSLDoConnect;
         // Here i wanna do a Postrequest to the ssl webserver
       end
       else
       // Here i wanna do a Postrequest to the non-ssl webserver
  finally
    Socket.Free;
    Response.Free;
    SynHttp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I wanna connect to a ssl webserver and if i connected successfully i want to perform a POST to the webserver.

Comment: What is your **real** question? Connect to a WebServer with SSL or perform a POST?

Comment: Maybe this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334141/how-to-establish-a-secure-connection-by-using-synapse

Comment: I wanna connect to a ssl webserver and if i connected successfully i want to perform a POST to the webserver.

Comment: Which one of them? 1) Connect to a WebServer with SSL or 2)perform a POST

Comment: Perform a normal post to a webserver without ssl is no problem for me, but i donÄt know how to handle it with ssl.

Comment: It's the same with or without SSL from POST point of view

Comment: Ah ok but how do i connect correctly to a ssl server?

Comment: On the answer I gave you is an example on how to connect to SSL server by using SSLDoConnect;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the

> SendString

routine, as from their example [Using Tcp With Ssl On Tcp Client](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:tcpwithssl?s%5B%5D=ttcpblocksocket)

LE: from the comments OP posts I believe a good start will be this question

[How to establish a secure connection by using Synapse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334141/how-to-establish-a-secure-connection-by-using-synapse)

Comment: Is it possible to send a string like this?     Params := 'parameter1=' + EncodeURLElement('data1') + '&' +
              'parameter2=' + EncodeURLElement('data2');

Comment: That depends on what you need to request from your server. I answered to your question. This is another question